# What is the equivalent of isScrollEnabled for a List in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13, swiftui-list

With anything in `UIKit` that inherits from `UIScrollView`, there is a property `isScrollEnabled` that allows you to disable scrolling for the view.

Looking through the [documentation for ScrollView in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview), I have yet to find an equivalent.

The closest is the `.disabled()` function, but that is the equivalent of `.isUserInteractionEnabled` from `UIKit`, which is not what I want.